# Scoring system for events

Tags: java, beginner

A newbie here. I have done this assignment that my university gave.

**Requirements**

- Participants may enter the tournament as individuals or as part of a team**
- It is expected that will be 4 teams each with 5 members and there will be 20 spaces for individual competitors
- Each team or individual will complete 5 events
- Each event will be defined as a team or individual event
- The events will vary in type, from sporting to academic challenges
- Individuals and teams will be awarded points according to their rank within each event
- The points awarded for each event are as yet undecided and the college are willing to hear any suggestions you may have
- Also the college would like to include the possibility of entering for one event only

I would like to know if my code is good enough or not. Or if there is more to be added and fixed.

When reviewing my program, kindly consider the following.

- Suitability for audience and purpose of Scoring System
- Meet criteria
- Ease of Use
- Quality of the software solution
  e.g. reliability, usability, efficiency/performance, maintainability,
- constraints, , programmer knowledge
- Strengths and weaknesses of my software
- Improvements that can be made
- Optimising software solutions, e.g. improving robustness, improving efficiency of the code, adding additional functionality

CODE

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScoreSystem {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        // explanation of rules to the client to provide what the program is capable of
        System.out.println("Scoring System");
        System.out.println("\nScoring System Rules" + "\nNormal Scoring Rules\n" +
                "Rank 1 gives 20 points for Normal Teams and Participants");
        System.out.println("Rank 2 gives 10 points and Rank 3 gives 5 points");
        System.out.println("Rank 4 and lower will not receive any points\n");
        System.out.println("For Special Teams and Individuals");
        System.out.println("Rank 1 gives 100 points , Rank 2 Gives 80 points and Rank 3 Gives 60 points");
        System.out.println("Rank 4 or lower will not give any points");
        System.out.println("Constant Rules");
        System.out.println("5 Events are set for Normal Teams and Individuals");
        System.out.println("Only 1 event is allowed for Special Teams and Individuals ");
        System.out.println("There can only be 5 participants in both normal and special team\n");
        System.out.println("Common Rules");
        System.out.println("Normal Teams and Participants will participate in 5 events");
        System.out.println("Special Teams and Participants will participate in only 1 event");

// the start of teams
        // number of teams

        System.out.println("-----Teams------");
        System.out.println("Enter Amount of Teams Entering 5 EVENTS");
        int teamNo = scan.nextInt();

        String[] teamName = new String[teamNo];
        int[] teamScore = new int[teamNo];
        String[] Tevent = new String[5];
        String[] teamPart = new String[teamNo * 5];
        int teamRank;
        int eventNo = 5;
// condition check for number of teams
        // skip all of team code if 0

        if (teamNo == 0) {
        } else {
            // event names
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Event Name " + (i + 1) + " for the teams");
                Tevent[i] = scan.next();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < teamNo; i++) {
                // participant names for the teams
                for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Participant name " + (a + 1) + " for team " + (i + 1));
                    teamPart[i] = scan.next();
                }
            }

// name and rank of the teams

            for (int i = 0; i < teamNo; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Name of team " + (i + 1));
                teamName[i] = scan.next();

                for (int a = 0; a < eventNo; a++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter rank of the team on the event " + (a + 1));
                    teamRank = scan.nextInt();
                    int tRank = 0;
                    // scoring system for the teams
                    switch (teamRank) {
                        case 3:
                            tRank = 5;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            tRank = 10;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            tRank = 20;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (teamRank == 0 || teamRank >= 4) {
                        System.out.println("This team will not be awarded points");
                    } else {
                        teamScore[i] += tRank;
                        System.out.println(tRank + " points is granted for this event");
                    }

                    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                        scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
// the start of individual participants
        // number of individuals

        System.out.println("-----Individuals-----");
        int PartNo;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter the number of individuals participating 5 EVENTS" + " LIMITED SPACE OF 20");
            PartNo = scan.nextInt();
        } while (PartNo > 20);

        String[] PartName = new String[PartNo];
        int[] PartScore = new int[PartNo];
        String[] Pevent = new String[5];
        int PartRank;

// condition checking
        // skip all code for individual if 0

        if (PartNo == 0) {
        } else {
            // event name for the individuals
            System.out.println("Enter the 5 event names for participants ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Name of the event " + (i + 1) + " that the individuals are entering");
                Pevent[i] = scan.next();
            }
            // name and rank of the individuals
            for (int i = 0; i < PartNo; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter name of Individual " + (i + 1));
                PartName[i] = scan.next();

                for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter rank of the individual on the event " + (a + 1));
                    PartRank = scan.nextInt();
                    int pRank = 0;
                    // start of scoring system for the individuals
                    switch (PartRank) {
                        case 3:
                            pRank = 5;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            pRank = 10;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            pRank = 20;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (PartRank == 0 || PartRank >= 4) {
                        System.out.println("This team will not be awarded points");
                    } else {
                        PartScore[i] += pRank;
                        System.out.println(pRank + " points is granted for this event");
                    }

                    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                        scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Special Teams and Individuals Represent Teams and Individuals entering only 1 event");
        System.out.println(" If there are no Special Teams or Individuals Enter 0 when the amount is asked");

// the start of special teams
        // number of special teams

        System.out.println("-----Special_Teams-----");
        System.out.println("Enter Amount of Teams Entering only 1 EVENT");
        int SpecTeamNo = scan.nextInt();


        String[] SpecTeamName = new String[SpecTeamNo];
        String[] STevent = new String[1];
        int[] SpecTeamScore = new int[SpecTeamNo];
        String[] SteamPart = new String[(20 - PartNo) * 5];
        int sTeamRank;

// condition checking for number of special teams
        //skip if 0

        if (SpecTeamNo == 0) {
        } else {
            // event for special team
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Event Name " + (i + 1) + " for the teams");
                STevent[i] = scan.next();
            }
            // participant name for special team
            for (int a = 0; a < SpecTeamNo; a++) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Participant name " + (i + 1) + " for team " + (a + 1));
                    SteamPart[i] = scan.next();
                }
            }

// name and rank of special teams

            for (int i = 0; i < SpecTeamNo; i++) {
                System.out.println("Enter Name of team " + (i + 1));
                SpecTeamName[i] = scan.next();

                for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter rank of the team on the event");
                    sTeamRank = scan.nextInt();
                    int stRank = 0;
                    // scoring system for special team
                    switch (sTeamRank) {
                        case 3:
                            stRank = 60;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            stRank = 80;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            stRank = 100;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (sTeamRank == 0 || sTeamRank >= 4) {
                        System.out.println("This team will not be awarded points");
                    } else {
                        SpecTeamScore[i] += stRank;
                        System.out.println(stRank + " points is granted for this event");
                    }

                    if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                        scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

// the start of special individuals
        // number of special individuals

        System.out.println("-----Special_Individuals-----");
        if (PartNo == 20) {
            System.out.println("No special individuals will be added as only 20 individuals are allowed");
        } else {
            int SpecPartNo;
            do {
                System.out.println("only 20 spaces are available for individuals and special individuals combined ");
                System.out.println("Please Enter Appropriate Amount of Participants");
                System.out.println("Enter Number of Individuals only Entering 1 event ");
                SpecPartNo = scan.nextInt();
            } while (SpecPartNo > 20 - PartNo);

            String[] SpecPartName = new String[SpecPartNo];
            String[] SPevent = new String[1];
            int[] SpecPartScore = new int[SpecPartNo];

//condition checking number of special individuals
            //skip all codes for special individuals if 0

            if (SpecPartNo == 0) {
            } else {
                // event for the special individuals
                for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Event Name " + (i + 1) + " for the individuals");
                    SPevent[i] = scan.next();
                }

// name and rank input of special individuals

                for (int i = 0; i < SpecPartNo; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Enter Name of individual " + (i + 1));
                    SpecPartName[i] = scan.next();

                    for (int a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
                        System.out.println("Enter rank of the individual on the event");
                        int sPartRank = scan.nextInt();
                        int spRank = 0;
                        // scoring system for the individuals
                        switch (sPartRank) {
                            case 3:
                                spRank = 60;
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                spRank = 80;
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                spRank = 100;
                                break;
                        }
                        if (sPartRank == 0 || sPartRank >= 4) {
                            System.out.println("This individual will not be awarded points");
                        } else {
                            SpecPartScore[i] += spRank;
                            System.out.println(spRank + " points is granted for this event");
                        }

                        if (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                            scan.nextLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


// output for all teams and individuals with their respective events and scores

            if (teamNo == 0) {
                System.out.println("There are no teams");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Amount of Teams: " + PartNo);
                System.out.println("Events Participated : 5");
                System.out.println("\t'Events List for Teams' : " + Arrays.asList(Tevent) + "\n");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\tTeam\tParticipants");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                for (int i = 0; i < PartNo; i++) {

                    System.out.println("| Team': " + teamName[i] + "\n" + "Participants " + teamPart[i] + "\n");
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                }
                System.out.println("Scores are shown respectively ");
                System.out.println("All Teams Scores : " + Arrays.toString(teamScore));
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
            if (PartNo == 0) {
                System.out.println("There are no teams\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Amount of Participants: " + PartNo);
                System.out.println("Events Participated : 5");
                System.out.println("\t'Events List for Teams' : " + Arrays.asList(Pevent) + "\n");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\t\tIndividual\nScore");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                for (int i = 0; i < PartNo; i++) {

                    System.out.println(" | \t'Individual Name': " + PartName[i]);

                }
                System.out.println("Scores are shown respectively ");
                System.out.println(" All Individual Scores:" + Arrays.toString(PartScore));
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }

            if (SpecTeamNo == 0) {
                System.out.println("There is no Special Teams");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Amount of Special Teams " + SpecTeamNo);
                System.out.println("Events Participated : 1");
                System.out.println("\t'Events List for Teams' : " + Arrays.asList(STevent) + "\n");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("\tSpecial Team\tParticipants\tScore");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                for (int i = 0; i < SpecTeamNo; i++) {

                    System.out.println("| \t'Special Team Name': " + SpecTeamName[i] + "\n" + "Special Team Participants " + SteamPart[i]);

                }
                System.out.println("Scores are shown respectively ");
                System.out.println("ALl Special Team Scores: " + Arrays.toString(SpecTeamScore));
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            }
            if (PartNo == 20) {
                System.out.println("There are No Special Individuals");
            } else {
                if (SpecPartNo == 0) {
                    System.out.println("There are  no Special Individuals");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Amount of Special Individuals " + SpecPartNo);
                    System.out.println("Events Participated : 1");
                    System.out.println("\t'Events List for Teams' : " + Arrays.asList(SPevent) + "\n");
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("\tSpecial Individual\tScore");
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    for (int i = 0; i < SpecPartNo; i++) {

                        System.out.println("| \t'Special Individual Name': " + SpecPartName[i]);

                    }
                    System.out.println("Scores are shown respectively ");
                    System.out.println("All Special Individuals Scores: " + Arrays.toString(SpecPartScore));
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how the program is and if the output would be to your liking.
And if there is anything else I should  add.

Answer (score 3):

Java is an object-oriented language. If I were teaching a Java course and marking an assignment, one of the things I'd be looking at would be whether the student has applied object-oriented principles to their program.

As it's written, your code is entirely procedural with all the program logic in the `main()` method. `main()` should serve only as an entry point to your program, with the rest of the logic separated into classes and methods. I won't try to do the job of your professor by explaining OOP, but a starting point might be to look at the problem statements and list the noun phrases to identify the concepts you might want to represent as classes. This gives us:

- `Tournament`
- `Event`
- `Team`
- Individual (which you might refer to as `Competitor`)

Further analysis will give some clues about what methods these classes might contain or how they might be extended:

```
class Event {
  // The events will vary in type, from sporting to academic challenges
  EventType eventType;
}

enum EventType {
     ARCHERY, BOXING, SPELLING_BEE // ...
}

// Each event will be defined as a team or individual event
class TeamEvent extends Event {
    Map<Team, Integer> scores;
}

class IndividualEvent extends Event {
    Map<Competitor, Integer> scores;
}
```

Note that these are just some ideas, and there's no single correct way to implement these. I won't try to do your homework for you by implementing them fully.

You've also hard-coded the scoring system, meaning that if a user wanted to run a tournament that was scored differently they'd need to rewrite the code. Instead, consider a method of `Tournament` which looks at the `Event`s played and the positions of each `Team` or `Competitor` in each, assigning points accordingly.